# comparing 'clienterror' to a 'string' in python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the output of a clienterror message to a string in python, but I can't get it to work.
Is this kind of thing possible ?

I have tried 3 ways to solve it: (A) (I get no output)

```
    except ClientError as e:
    a = "An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Stack [name] does not exist"
    b = "An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: No updates are to be performed."
    if e is a:
        print ('Stack [name] does not exist')
    if e == b:
        print ('No updates are to be performed')
```

(B)

```
print e[5]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
--
    print (e[76:])
()
    print (e[:-1])
()
```

(C)
I'm trying to understand how many parts are to the sentence, by running

```
        print (len(e))
```

But I get "TypeError: object of type 'ClientError' has no len()"

So... can't I really compare the ClientErrorto a string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't compare a string to an exception. They aren't the same type. `is` will only return true if they are *literally* the same object. Even `==` wouldn't work here since as mentioned, they aren't the same type.

You can however cast the exception to a string, then use `in` to see if it contains the message:

```
ex_str = str(e)
a = "does not exist"

if a in ex_str:
    print ('Stack [name] does not exist')
```

The `in` check will only work however if `str(e)` includes the full error message. If it doesn't, you'll need to get the message another way. How exception messages are handled depends on the subclass, and I don't have access to a `ClientError` object to test; nor can I find a definition of it anywhere online.